# Almost a Frechet distribution but not quite yet

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have function as $$\frac{2}{\alpha}x^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-1}e ^{-x^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}}$$

This kind of reminds me of the Weibull and Frechet distribution but not quite because if it were I should be having a distribution like
$$\frac{2}{\alpha}x^{\frac{2}{\alpha}-1}e ^{-x^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}}$$

Any ideas of how I can tranfom my function into Frechet distribution, because I would like to take advantage of Frechet distribution integral properties.

Comment: I think all you can do is to take $y$ such that $x^{-2/\alpha} = y^{-1/\alpha}$, i.e. $y=x^2$. Then do the change of variable and see what you get.

Comment: I dont think it works @Ian

Comment: I don't think you have a Frechet distribution in the first place, which is why I said "all you can do".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$
\eqalign{f(x,\alpha) &= \dfrac{1}{\alpha} x^{2/\alpha - 1} \exp(-x^{1/\alpha})\cr
g(x,\alpha) &= \dfrac{2}{\alpha} x^{2/\alpha - 1} \exp(-x^{2/\alpha})}$$
Note that the normalization for $f(x,\alpha)$ is different from your function by a factor of $1/2$: 
this is what is needed to make $f(x,\alpha)$ the density for a probability measure on $(0,\infty)$.

The cumulative distribution functions corresponding to these are

$$ \eqalign{F(x,\alpha) &= \int_0^x f(t,\alpha)\; dt = 1 - (x^{1/\alpha} + 1) \exp(-x^{1/\alpha})\cr
   G(x,\alpha) &=  \int_0^x g(t,\alpha)\; dt =1 - \exp(-x^{2/\alpha})}$$

If you want an increasing function $h$ such that $h(X)$ has density 
$g(x,\alpha)$ when $X$ has density $f(x,\alpha)$ you want
$$ (x^{1/\alpha} + 1) \exp(-x^{1/\alpha}) = \exp(-h(x)^{2/\alpha})$$
and thus
$$ h(x) = \left( x^{1/\alpha} - \ln(1 + x^{1/\alpha})\right)^{\alpha/2} $$

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, I was wondering if you can help me find the $$\mathbb{E}_f [ 1-\frac{1}{1+sx^{-1}}] $$ and $$\mathbb{E}_f[e^{-sx^{-1}}]$$where f is the distribution  $f(x,\alpha)$.

Comment: The first can be written in the form
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{t}^{a+1}{{\rm e}^{-t}}}{s+{t}^{a}}}
\,{\rm d}t
$$
which doesn't seem to have a closed form.  However, for positive integers $a$ you can do a partial-fractions expansion and express it in terms of the Ei (exponential integral) function.

Comment: It also has an asymptotic series is $s$:
$$ \dfrac{\Gamma(a+2)}{s} - \dfrac{\Gamma(2a+2)}{s^2} + \dfrac{\Gamma(3a+2)}{s^3} - \ldots $$

Comment: Similarly, $\mathbb E_f [\exp(-s/x)]$ doesn't seem to have a closed form.  For $a=1$ it can be written in terms of the Bessel K function, for other positive rational values of $a$ it seems to be expressible in terms of the Meijer G function.